# Logistic ODE with negative initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, computational-science

For the ODE with negative initial condition, say for example
\begin{align*}
 \dot{x}= rx\left(1-\dfrac{x}{K}\right),x(0)=-K
\end{align*}

From the phase portrait, $x(t)$ should converge to $-\infty$ as $t\to \infty$. However, this is my exact solution for it:
\begin{align*}
 &\dot{x} =rx\left(1-\dfrac{x}{K}\right) \\
 \Leftrightarrow &\left[\dfrac{1}{x\left(1-\frac{x}{K}\right)}\right]dx = rdt \\
 \Leftrightarrow & \left[\dfrac{1-\frac{x}{K}+\frac{x}{K}}{x\left(1-\frac{x}{K}\right)}\right]dx = rdt\\
 \Leftrightarrow&\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{K-x}\right)dx = rdt.\\
\end{align*}
Integrate both sides, we claim that
\begin{align*}
 \ln|x|-\ln|K-x|=rt+\ln C,
\end{align*}
where $C>0$. Therefore we get
\begin{align*}
 &\left|\dfrac{x}{K-x}\right|=Ce^{rt}\\
 \Leftrightarrow&\dfrac{x}{K-x}=\pm Ce^{rt}.
\end{align*}
Since $C$ can be any positive number, then $\pm C$ can take on any non-zero value, so that we can introduce the solution of the form
\begin{align} 
 \dfrac{x}{K-x}=Ce^{rt},
\end{align}
where $C \in \mathbb{R}, C\ne 0$ so
\begin{align*}
 x(t) = \dfrac{CKe^{rt}}{1+Ce^{rt}}.
\end{align*}
For the initial condition $x_0=-K$. So, we get
\begin{align*}
   -K=C\left(K+K\right) \Leftrightarrow C=-\dfrac{1}{2}.
  \end{align*}
So the solution in this case is
\begin{align*}
   x(t) = \dfrac{-1/2Ke^{rt}}{1-1/2 e^{rt}}=\dfrac{-1/2K}{e^{-rt}-1/2} \to K,
  \end{align*}
as $t \to \infty$ (since $r>0$ then $0<e^{-r}<1$ so $e^{-rt}\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$), which is not true due to the phase portrait. Can someone please show me where I get It wrong please? Thank you!

Comment: You solution ends at the pole where $e^{rt}=2$. The behavior of the formula after that is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain more into this? Thank you

Comment: Ah so you mean that the denominator should be different than 0 right?

Comment: Yes. The solution goes to minus infinity, there is no coming back from that.